# Facing a problem while switching frames with Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java

I have a problem with switching frames in Selenium. I'm using Firefox Webdriver.

In the first step I'm switching to `Masterpass_frame` then I click on a button to force the frame to reload. Then I need to put values into the login form which is in `MasterPass_wallet_frame`.

I've tried switching to the `MasterPass_wallet_frame` by `switchTo.defaultContent()` and then `switchTo.frame("MasterPass_wallet_frame")` but nothing is happening.

Do you have any ideas how to do that? It's my first big problem in Selenium. I'm still learning.

This is the html code

```
<div id="MasterPass_container">
<iframe id="MasterPass_frame" frameborder="0" src="https://sandbox.masterpass.com/lightbox/version232/Switch/index.html?allowedCardTypes=master%2Camex%2Cdiners%2Cdiscover%2Cjcb%2Cmaestro%2Cvisa&allowedLoyaltyPrograms=&allowedShipToCountries=US%2CAU%2CBE%2CBR%2CCA%2CCN%2CFR%2CIL%2CIT%2CNL%2CRO%2CSG%2CES%2CSE%2CAE%2CGB&shippingLocationProfile=&callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.masterpass.com%2FCheckout%2FMerchantDemoCallback%3Fconsumer_key%3DNeqwj09Ay7dYCB0D38HwjrEbyAWQpsgbdKYdjPTtdbe4fe96!467a4c6c7341586a584d5a554766526a7154786a4b513d3d&flow=checkout&locale=en-US&merchantCheckoutId=a4a6w3nlg59yjh02zn7v21h030a78pon&requestedDataTypes=&requestToken=ca01084580335b3c432ffbc2743055108737284b&version=v6&pairingRequestToken=108f1df6326733182b551bdc045db70c483d1024&requireShippingDestination=true&clientOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.masterpass.com&targetOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.masterpass.com" allowtransparency="true" name="MasterPass_frame">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="js canvas geolocation video audio localstorage sessionstorage texttrackapi track formvalidation fieldsetdisabled styleableinputrange no-details" lang="en-us">
<head>
<body id="iframe-body" class="switch-frame">
<div id="MasterPass_animation_overlay" class=""></div>
<div id="closeContainer">
<div id="headerPanel" style="display: block;">
<div id="topNotificationContainer" class="">
<div class="top-notification-overlay"></div>
<div id="mainPanel">
<div id="walletWindow" class="mp-frame">
<iframe id="MasterPass_wallet_frame" frameborder="0" height="590" width="690" style="height:100%;" allowtransparency="true" src="https://wallet.beta.upaid.pl/portfel?merchant_return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.masterpass.com%2Flightbox%2Fversion232%2FSwitch%2Fcallback.html%3Foauth_token%3Dca01084580335b3c432ffbc2743055108737284b&flow=checkout&locale=en-PL&targetOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.masterpass.com&clientOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.masterpass.com&walletId=uPaidV6b&acceptable_cards=master%2Camex%2Cdiners%2Cdiscover%2Cjcb%2Cmaestro%2Cvisa&checkout_identifier=a4a6w3nlg59yjh02zn7v21h030a78pon&requestedDataTypes=&oauth_token=ca01084580335b3c432ffbc2743055108737284b&pairingRequestToken=108f1df6326733182b551bdc045db70c483d1024&checkout_version=6&merchant_name=andresTest638&auth_options=NO_3DS&cardinal_merchant_id=mcpaypass&amount=2500&currency=840&order_number=1450682352687&suppress_shipping_address=false&merchantSuppressSignup=false">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body class="pl">
<div class="main-window">
<div id="sidebar-container">
<div class="main-layout-container ">
<div style="height: 100%;">
<div class="main-content login">
<form class="form-horizontal max-height" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://wallet.beta.upaid.pl/auth/login" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="ayF6G1K5HJvpmcx8ikaGCBgzjw3gvFuYyhCsdf7U" name="_token">
<input type="hidden" value="ayF6G1K5HJvpmcx8ikaGCBgzjw3gvFuYyhCsdf7U" name="_token">
<input id="loginType" type="hidden" value="WEB" name="loginType">
<div class="container-fluid max-height">
<header class="content-header">
<div class="modal fade languageModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myLanguageModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="row wrapp wrappedd">
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-4">
<div class="wallet-logo"></div>
<div class="advertising">
<span id="sm-app-link" class="blued sm-blued link full-display" data-target=".downloadModal" data-toggle="modal">Pobierz aplikację Wallet</span>
<a id="app-link-mobile-large" class="blued sm-blued link" target="_blank" href="https://upaid.pl/app" style="display: none">Pobierz aplikację Wallet</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h4 class="disnone">Wybierz sposób akceptacji płatności</h4>
<div class="disnone sign-in-buttons-container">
<div class="web">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<input id="prefix" class="prefix-switch form-control" type="text" value="+48" name="prefix" data-target=".prefixModal" data-toggle="modal" readonly="readonly">
<input class="login-input form-control" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Adres e-mail lub numer telefonu">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 errors-red"> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
</div>
<div class="mobile" style="display: none;">
<div class="forget-password col-xs-12">
</div>
</div>
<hr class="big-margin-hr">
<div class="row">
</div>
</div>
<footer class="main-footer">
</div>
</form>
<div id="safari-user-modal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="safariInfo" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any exception ??

Comment: It seems you have nested frame, so first switch to `MasterPass_frame` , then switch to `MasterPass_wallet_frame` , Then you can find element. And to switch in to frame does not require `switchto.defaultcontent`.

Comment: Hi, I changed the OS from Ubuntu to Windows and the problem has gone. On win everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to switch to `MasterPass_frame` and then `MasterPass_wallet_frame`

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='MasterPass_frame']")));

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='MasterPass_wallet_frame']")));
```

and then try finding elements of login form and insert values in it.